# Debugging with gdbserver using serial connection (Not TCP) doesn't work

Tags: gdb, embedded-linux, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug a program on my board which runs an embedded linux and I have Ubuntu as host system. I have a big problem with gdbserver. You see the thing is that my board doesn't have an Ethernet interface but a serial device which I'm using for console and I noticed that you can use a serial device for debugging in gdbserver although I couldn't find an example of this considering everyone that used gdbserver in videos or books used it in TCP mode which I can't do that. 
So What I did was simply running gdbserver on the board this way:

```
root@DM368# gdbserver /dev/ttyS0 hello
Process hello created; pid = 472
```

On the host side I'm using ddd program and I ran:

```
root@mosi-VirtualBox:~# ddd --debugger arm-linux-gdb
```

And in ddd window terminal I entered:

```
(gdb) cd /root/home/mySimpleHello/hello
(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyUSB0
(gdb) file hello
```

And /dev/ttyUSB0 is connected to the board's /dev/ttyS0

But I don't get anything back in gdb and there is nothing in gdbserver output which is kind of weird. I mean not a single message like a "host connected" or "remote debugging from ..." or things like that. And in ddd when I ran:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x83ac: file hello.c, line 10.
(gdb) run
```

Then gdb says:

```
the program in not being run
```

I tried with gdb on Ubuntu's terminal directly (whitout ddd) and the same thing happened. I even tried with eclipse and I setup a debugging profile in eclipse and I installed gdb-multiarch program and used that in eclipse with its .gdbinit file set to arm. Nothing happens and I have no idea why this simple procedure wouldn't work.

Does somebody have any idea? What am I doing wrong? How can I debug a program using a serial connection?

Comment: I have never used gdbserver over serial before, but I wanted to point out that if you have USB on the board, then you can build USB-network drivers and you will have a network interface (on USB connection to you copmuter) that you can use with gdbserver.

Comment: Thank you. It's just according to documentations it's possible to use a serial port: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_130.html. I did the exact same thing but I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: I mean what if the problem was something else? I'm saying this because it was supposed to work with a serial connection.  BTW you mean to use a USB to Ethernet Adapter ?  Wow! I've never done that. So after rebuilding the kernel and plug in a USB to Ethernet Adapter I should see something like eth0 after running $ifconfig?  What should I change in kernel and how can I be sure that this kernel supports the adapter I'm planning to buy?

Comment: Yes, you can have an eth0 over USB. You will have to enable the config option CONFIG_USB_ETH (enable USB and USB Gadgets) in your board kernel. I have not done this for a while, but I figure if you enable USB_ETH on your PC too, you can just use a USB cable between PC and board, and finally configure same IP addresses on both ends.

Comment: I'm sorry but don't you mean CONFIG_USB_USBNET? or USBNET is for hardware adaptors only? I got confused! I've never heard about using a single direct USB cable between PC and board for establishing a network interface!